# Setting the UserControl property to child controls - WPF, Silverlight 

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding, user-controls

I have a Usercontrol with a Button and TextBlock in it.
I would like to set the Background of both Button and TextBlock with the Background of the Usercontrol.(ie, I am trying to Bind to the usercontrol's Background property).

Please let me know how can I do this in XAML.

Is there any difference for this in Silverlight and WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to a Ancestor control such as:

```
<Button Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=Background}"/>
```

The same will work for the TextBlock, but its Background is already transparent

According to [this](http://coreclr.wordpress.com/2009/11/09/relativesource-binding-in-silverlight-3/) Silverlight does not support FindAncestor

Answer (score 1):

Use TemplateBinding:

```
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">                        
                    <TextBlock Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Text="something"/>                        
                </Border>
```

Just set both the top level control in your usercontrol (a border in my case) and the TextBlock to use the TemplateBinding Background.